# Sustainability of wood pellet sources for biomass boiler

Tags: energy, heating, uk, biomass

We're considering a biomass boiler for our guesthouse (1820 vintage with corresponding energy issues).  The opportunity to reduce gas usage and the economics of the RHI scheme in the UK (a sort-of feed-in tariff for logs) would seem to make this a no-brainer choice.

However, word-of-mouth comments question whether the *source* of wood pellets for the boiler is itself very sustainable.

Does anyone have any **reliable** references or pointers where I can learn more about this?

---

Edit: have found this one from Ethical Consumer. http://www.ethicalconsumer.org/buyersguides/energy/biomassboilers.aspx

---

*PS. We have considered wood chip, and log, variants of biomass boilers which avoids the pellet manufacturing process and would offer better chances of a geographical local source.  There are various logistical issues with these in our particular circumstances.*

Comment: Am I right that the site you've edited in is a (partial) answer to your question? If so, perhaps you can post it as an answer?

Comment: @THelper Done. I'd hesitated doing so, hoping to get better answers but I can understand the reasoning for posting answers as answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the sustainability depends strongly on how the pellets are produced. Often pellets are made from by-product from other forest industry which makes it trickier to calculate emission and carbon footprint.

I took a quick look at IEA (International Energy Agency) and they had a general article about bio-energy:
http://www.iea.org/techinitiatives/renewableenergy/bioenergy/

They also refer to a book about pellets "The Pellet Handbook", haven't bought or read it thou:
http://www.routledge.com/books/details/9781844076314/

Comment: Good link, especially if you drill through the main site http://www.ieabioenergy.com/ and the links on the newsletters.  That said, I'd be a touch suspicious that they are coming from a solely energy production perspective rather than a broader sustainability one. E.g. it could be that their _numbers_ could be used to argue for chopping down rainforests or other important ecologies, but I'd not consider that 'sustainable' in a wider sense. Neither, probably, would they, but it's not a factor in their evaluations as far as I can see.

Comment: http://www.iea.org/techinitiatives/renewableenergy/bioenergy/ The content you are looking for does not exist, or has been moved.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial self-answer. While I'm generally happy with EC's information some of the linked sites are not ones that strike me as 'reliable' sources of facts, so I am am still rather hoping more answers will follow.

From Ethical Consumer: http://www.ethicalconsumer.org/buyersguides/energy/biomassboilers.aspx